# Accurev - query for issues with changes

Tags: accurev

Is there a way using the Accurev client or command line to query all the issues (in a specific state) that have file changes associated with them? 
If you use the Accurev client, and open an issue, the Changes tab lists the changed files. However, when creating an issues query expression, I don't see any fields that indicate the changed files (or even if there are changed files).

Comment: Please add more info. Also, an example on what you have tried would be great. Your question is also a little short and contains little info about the problem itself..

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the "cpkdescribe" query to pull that information.  A "queryIssue" query retrieves all the other fields, but not the change package data.

See the AccuRev_User_CLI.pdf manual that is included with your installation of AccuRev.